# Determining distribution of mix of discrete and contionus random variables

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

This question concerns probability theory. I have a random variable $X$ with the density

$$
\begin{align}
f_{X}(x) = \frac{2}{\pi\sqrt{(1-x^{2})}},\quad 0<x<1.
\end{align}
$$

Furthermore let $Z$ denote a random variable with Bernoulli distribution (i.e. discrete) that takes the values $-1$ and $1$ with equal probability,

$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(Z=1)=\mathbb{P}(Z=-1)=1/2.
\end{align}
$$

I would like to find out what distribution the following random variable has:

$$
\begin{align}
U = Z\arcsin{(X)}.
\end{align}
$$

As can be seen it is a mix of discrete and contionus random variables. My attempt at a solution is this: I add an auxiliary equation/random variable and use the transformation theorem.

$$
\begin{align}
U &= Z\arcsin{(X)},\\
Y &= \arcsin{(X)} \equiv g(X),
\end{align}
$$

which has the inversion

$$
\begin{align}
X &= \sin{(Y)} \equiv h_{1}(u,y),\\
Z &= U/Y \equiv h_{2}(u,y).
\end{align}
$$

The distribution of $Y$ can be computed:

$$
\begin{align}
f_{Y}(y) = f_{X}\left(g^{-1}(y)\right)\frac{d}{dy}g^{-1}(y) = \frac{2}{\pi\sqrt{1-\sin^{2}{(y)}}}\cdot \cos{(y)} = \frac{2}{\pi},\quad 0<y<\pi/2.
\end{align}
$$

Evidently $Y\sim \text{U}(0,\pi/2)$ (uniformely distributed). With this piece of information I may finally compute the desired distribution of $U$. We need the Jacobian of the transformation, then I may apply the transformation theorem.

$$
\begin{align}
\mathbf{J}(u,y) &= \begin{pmatrix}\frac{\partial}{\partial u}h_{1}(u,y)&\frac{\partial}{\partial y}h_{1}(u,y)\\\frac{\partial}{\partial u}h_{2}(u,y)&\frac{\partial}{\partial y}h_{2}(u,y)\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}0&\cos{(y)}\\1/y&-u/y^{2}\end{pmatrix}, \\[5mm]
\det{(\mathbf{J}(u,y))} &= -\cos{(y)}/y.
\end{align}
$$

Finally I use the transformation theorem:
$$
\begin{align}
f_{U,Y}(u,y) &= f_{X,Z}(h_{1}(u,y),h_{2}(u,y))\vert \mathbf{J}(u,y)\vert = \{\text{Independence}\} = f_{X}(h_{1}(u,y))f_{Z}(h_{2}(u,y))\vert \mathbf{J}(u,y)\vert \\
&=\frac{2}{\pi\sqrt{1-\sin^{2}{(y)}}}\cdot \frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{\cos{(y)}}{y}=\frac{1}{\pi y} = \frac{2}{\pi}\cdot \frac{1}{2y}.
\end{align}
$$

It seems as though, since the joint density factorizes, that $U$ has marginal density $f_{U}=\frac{1}{2y}$, but that cannot be right (it cannot depend on $y$). Apparently $U$ should be uniformely distributed over the interval $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$. How do I show this? My feeling is that I have made some error when inserting the distribution for $Z$, I do not really know how to handle mixed joint densities like this.

Edit: so I thought about this some more, maybe I was little quick to stop at joint density. Is it not possible to integrate the joint density over the state space of $Y$ to obain the marginal density of $U$? I will try and do this.